# Is it possible to FTP from a file server directly to S3 without going through EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to transfer files from a FTP server to S3. Usually, I would FTP to EC2 and from there load to S3. Was wondering if there is a way to transfer directly from FTP server to S3?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 does not support the FTP protocol.

However, you could certainly run some software on the machine that is hosting FTP, which talks directly with Amazon S3. There is no need to use an Amazon EC2 instance to communicate with S3.

For example, the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has an `aws s3 sync` command that synchronizes files to/from Amazon S3. You could have users send their files to the FTP Server, which stores the files in a given directory. The server could then run the `aws s3 sync` command at regular intervals (eg every 5 minutes), which ensures that the files are copied up to S3.

You would simply need to load the AWS CLI onto the FTP Host.